# Changing the column Format with VBA causing RunTime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to add columns in an existing worksheet and run formulas. The first With-End with in the sub works. The second causes the Run Time error 1004 with the line:

```
.Range("N2:N").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Sub Format_Raw_SSPData()

    With Sheets("Raw SSP Data")
        .Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("D2:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RIGHT(RC[-1],4)"
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Raw SSP Data")
        .Columns("N:N").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("N2:N").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        .Range("N2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INT(RC[-1])"
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Raw SSP Data")
        .Columns("O:O").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("O2:O").NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
        .Range("O2:O" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-2]-RC[-1])"
    End With

End Sub
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

EDIT:

New code update as per taller's suggestion, but now the same runtime error is on this line:

```
.Range("O2:O" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=RC[-2]-RC[-1])"

Sub Format_Raw_SSPData()

    With Sheets("Raw SSP Data")
        .Columns("D:D").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("D2:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RIGHT(RC[-1],4)"
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Raw SSP Data")
        .Columns("N:N").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("N2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        .Range("N2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INT(RC[-1])"
    End With
    
    With Sheets("Raw SSP Data")
        .Columns("O:O").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("O2:O" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
        .Range("O2:O" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-2]-RC[-1])"
    End With

End Sub
```

All the proper formats have occurred with the code except that the last formula was not executed. I am not sure what the typo was or what the current error is pointing to.

Comment: There is a typo. Try `.Range("N:N").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"` OR `.Range("N2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"` .  `.Range("O2:O").NumberFormat` has the same issue.

Comment: Probably should be: `"=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"` without `)`.

Comment: @MGonet Thank you. That was the issue. The code now works as needed. Also want to thank Taller for their contribution.